# Second connection to sql server fails

Tags: java, sql, connection, sql-server-2012

I try to maintain multiple connections to a local SQL server. I wrote a simple program that implement this, and it worked fine on my server (SQL server 2008 R2). However, when I try to execute the same program on my PC (SQL server 2012) I get an execution exception when trying to initiate the second connection.

Here is the program that fails:

```
public static Connection getUpdateDbConnection()
{
    Connection conn=null;
    try {
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            JDBCuRL="jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\\SQL2012EITAJE:58704;user=***;password=***
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcUrl)
            conn.setReadOnly(false);
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    return conn;
}

public static void main(...){
...
Connection con1 = getUpdateDbConnection(); <-- executes fine
Connection con2 = getUpdateDbConnection(); <-- fails here
...
}
```

And here is the thrown exception:

```
WARNING: ConnectionID:2 Prelogin error: host localhost port 58704 Error reading prelogin response: Connection reset
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Connection reset
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1509)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.read(IOBuffer.java:1547)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.Prelogin(SQLServerConnection.java:1279)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1200)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.loginWithoutFailover(SQLServerConnection.java:1054)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:758)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)*
```

I increased the number of allowed connections in "SQL Server Management Studio" and restarted the SQL service, but it didn't solve the issue.
Any idea of how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: please submit SSCCE otherwise we can't help you here

Comment: try to change the login/tcp maximum number of connection too.